# Difference among values taking in consideration percentage difference and absolute difference

Tags: percentages

My problem is pretty much straightforward and trivial for the vast majority of you, but I would love to have any hints on how to resolve it.
I need to measure and rank the difference in product sold between $2$ years ($2020$ vs $2019$). But I must take into account two different differences for the following reasons:

- Client A in $2019$ ordered $20$k
- Client A in $2020$ ordered $100$k

Ok nice, this is a + $400$ % increase and + $80$k in absolute term.

- Client B in $2019$ ordered $1$ ML
- Client B in $2020$ ordered $1.5$ ML

Great, this is a + $50$ % increase (way less than before) and + 500k in absolute term.

This + $500$k increase is gold for me even if the percentage change is lower than + $400$ %. However, clients like Client A, who increases their spending capability so drastically must be rewarded as well in my analysis.

Do you have any idea on how to balance the two differences following my logic?

Comment: So just to clarify, you're asking about which of the two should take precedence? Because that sounds more like a philosophy or economic question to me.

Comment: I would simply love to explore any mathematical approach (if existing) to face my dualistc-problem @merelymyself

Comment: Looking at context, this isn't a mathematical question. But from my own unprofessional opinion, I feel that the ranking should look not at percentage but the actual numerical values.

Comment: Just come up with some formula (like absolute increase multiplied by percent increase) that gives you a score you like.  Picking the formula is dependent on how you weight these factors.

Comment: @merelymyself it is not for us to decide what is important to op...

Comment: @DonThousand let's suppose I'd weight the factor directly proportional to their difference (e.g. if the difference in percentage is almost equal to max difference in percentage, it will have an higher weight)

Comment: @Aneema That's fine, that's your design decision.